# How to pass a object parameter to the controller Spring mvc by an onclick

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a populated table with spring mvc, I want to grab the entire object and pass via parameter to a javascript function:
Sample:

```
  <tr th:each="prod : ${prods}">
    <td th:text="${prod.name}">Onions</td>
    <td th:text="${prod.price}">2.41</td>
    <td onclick="${prod}" >CLICK HERE</td>
  </tr>
```

But  this not work.

I want to do this to reuse data of object on another screen.

Comment: try to create a object in JQuery to get the field values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `jQuery`, then there is a plugin called `tabletojson` which will return the equivalent json string with all the table data. That json can then be passed to any other function and manipulated easily. I think, the cleanest way.

```
var table = $('#mytable').tableToJSON();
```

Otherwise, it is required to iterate through all the columns and push it to some array

```
var mytable = document.getElementById("mytable");
for (var i = 0, myrow; myrow = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows using "myrow"
   for (var j = 0, mycol; mycol = myrow.cells[j]; j++) {
     //iterate through all the columns using mycol

   }  
}
```

Comment: after converting how to retrieve the current line clicked?

Comment: getting a clicked row is very simple `$('#mytable').find('tr').click( function(){
  alert('clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});`